# Reading the route table on Solaris

Tags: network-programming, solaris, routes, netstat

I'm working on a C++ application on Solaris 11 that needs to read the network routes (similar to the output of "route" on Linux or "netstat -r" on Solaris).

What is the best way to do on Solaris ? Solaris doesn't support getting it via sysctl() on an AF_ROUTE socket, like FreeBSD does.

I don't want to fork netstat and parse the output.

Comment: See similar question answers here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486786/portable-way-in-c-to-get-the-routing-table/26617572#26617572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look to the Solaris way to implement netstat:
https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.bin/netstat/netstat.c